# Conectar Arduino ao SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, arduino

Estou querendo manter um banco de dados atualizado com as saídas dos sensores do Arduíno.
Gostaria de saber se é possível conectar diretamente o Arduíno ao SQL Server para envio e recebimento de dados.

Ou a única opção seria fazer uma aplicação intermediária entre os dois?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Arduino UNO/Mega e Similares

Em se tratando do Arduino que usam microcontroladores da linha AVR  como Arduino UNO e Arduino Mega, não há como implementar drivers clientes para o SQL Server, há um Driver SQL para o MySQL, porém não há nenhuma segurança em usar tais drivers já que estes não podem criptografar a conexão com o banco e preservar informações de autenticação, devido o Microcontrolador AVR ser 8 bits e não ter poder computacional para tais algoritmos.

### Arduino DUE e Similares

Já as versões similares ao Arduino DUE podem vir a ter drivers mais elaborados, porém ainda assim serão fracos no quesito segurança, mesmo usando a arquitetura ARM não terá sempre um cooprocessador matemático adequado as operações matemáticas necessárias para criptografia.

### Arduino Galileu, Yum e outros que usam Linux

As versões Arduino Galileo e Arduino Yum, podem ter drivers para SQL Server, mas ainda não foram disponibilizados, você pode vir a tentar adaptar algum driver para Linux nestes ambientes recompilando o driver.

### Em Geral

Em todos os casos realmente a melhor solução é ter um Broker que irá prover um certo nível de segurança, e adaptação das informações enviadas.

Comment: Boa exploração das opções! +1.

Answer (score 10):

Infelizmente não existem drivers nativos para SQL Server que você possa utilizar diretamente do Arduino.

Você pode utilizar uma aplicação Web como *broker* para postar valores dos seus sensores.

```
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // Aguardar a conexão da Serial
  }

  // Inicia conexão via Ethernet:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Falha na configuracao do DHCP");
    // Tente forçar um IP, caso o DHCP falhe:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // Aguardar a inicializacao da Ethernet
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("conectando...");

  if (client.connect("servidor", 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /recebedadossensores?s1=" + valor1 + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: servidor");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
```